# Oracle: Use of a custom function inside a cursor declaration

Tags: oracle, plsql

Inside a procedure, I declare a cursor. And inside the cursor declaration, I use a `datum_naar_dagdeel` function. The function itself determines the day-of-the-week plus part-of-the-day and turns that into an integer. See the code-abstract:

```
...
CURSOR c_teamvoorkeuren
IS
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.seq_afpraak
     , a.datum_start
     , t.code
     , ks.code
     , ks.naam
FROM afspraak a
   , team t
   , kamer_selectie ks
WHERE a.seq_aga_afspraak = p_seq_aga_afspraak
  AND t.seq_team = a.seq_team
  AND ks.seq_team = a.seq_team
  AND ks.dagdeel = instancename.datum_naar_dagdeel(a.datum_start)
...
```

What I found out so far:

- `GRANT EXECUTE` on the function has been given to `public`.
- Other custom functions used elsewhere inside the procedure, are working fine.
- The select statement with the function inside, works perfectly on its own. When running the select part I am getting the results I expect.
- When I replace `instancename.datum_naar_dagdeel(a.date_start)` with `1`, the for-loop that is executed later on, runs perfectly. With `1` being the outcome of the function for the given appointment I am testing the procedure with.
- However, when I use the function instead of `1`, the for-loop does not perform a single iteration. Thus me concluding it is the combination of a function inside a cursor that is causing the problem.

Am I trying to do the impossible when using a custom function in inside a cursor-declaration? Does it make a difference if it is a custom function or system function?

*Alternatively, I suspect I could build in a check that uses the function inside the for-loop itself. And when the check fails, use a `continue` statement to go to the next iteration step. However, that solution does not feel really clean.*

Comment: There is no exception handler... at least not yet. I will definitely try your suggestion. So I guess you suspect it should be able to work.

As I normally program in C#.Net or on SQL Server, it might take me a couple of attempts to make it work. And given the time here in Europe, it probably has to wait till Sunday or Monday.

Comment: In general the cursor should work. Maybe provide the code of function `datum_naar_dagdeel`

Comment: This seems like something that would be easily cleared up by stepping though it with the debugger. Presumably the function doesn't return the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to replicate what you explained; seems to be OK *in this example*.

Create a function (I'm returning a constant), connected as `mike`; granting `execute` to `public`:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return 20;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> grant execute on f_test to public;

Grant succeeded.
```

User `scott` will be using that function in cursor's `where` clause (line #6):

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2  is
  3    cursor c1 is
  4      select deptno, ename
  5      from emp
  6      where deptno = mike.f_test;
  7  begin
  8    for c1r in c1 loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line(c1r.deptno ||' '|| c1r.ename);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_test;
20 SMITH
20 JONES
20 SCOTT
20 ADAMS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So - yes, it works.

---

If function returns e.g. `null`, there's no output (of course there isn't):

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> exec p_test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Could you share function code, as well as sample `afspraak.datum_start` values? Maybe we'll notice something you don't.

Answer (score 0):

**Found it! (... finally)**

Apparently, the numbering of the day of the week can vary, depending on the session settings. And as people who read this might be able to guess by now, my development environment has different default settings than the production environment. I suspect it has to do with the `nls_language` setting.

So instead of "*Lets match with the reservation settings for Mondays*", the code tried to match with the non existing reservations for Sunday.

Only having test-data for Monday and not being familiar with Oracle, probably didn't help either. Know that I did feel encouraged by the feedback of everyone who responded to start debugging again this afternoon and want to thank you for your help.

For those still interested, below I've added the original code of the function. In the current version, I have altered the weekday numbering, starting with `1` on Monday.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION instancename.datum_naar_dagdeel(datumtijd DATE)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  weekdag NUMBER := 0;
  dagdeel NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  
  SELECT TO_CHAR(datumtijd, 'D') INTO weekdag FROM dual;
  IF (weekdag = 2) THEN dagdeel := dagdeel + 1;  END IF;  -- Maandagochtend
  IF (weekdag = 3) THEN dagdeel := dagdeel + 3;  END IF;  -- Disndagochtend
  IF (weekdag = 4) THEN dagdeel := dagdeel + 5;  END IF;  -- Woensdagochtend
  IF (weekdag = 5) THEN dagdeel := dagdeel + 7;  END IF;  -- Donderdagochtend
  IF (weekdag = 6) THEN dagdeel := dagdeel + 9;  END IF;  -- Vrijdagochtend
  IF (weekdag = 7) THEN dagdeel := dagdeel + 11; END IF;  -- Zaterdagochtend
  
  -- Als de afspraak in de middag is, dan +1
  IF (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(datumtijd, 'HH24')) >= 12) 
  THEN dagdeel := dagdeel + 1; 
  END IF; 
  
  RETURN dagdeel;
END;

-- Grants for Function
GRANT EXECUTE ON instancename.datum_naar_dagdeel TO PUBLIC;
GRANT DEBUG ON instancename.datum_naar_dagdeel TO PUBLIC;
```

Note: I've altered this response after first posting it. My final finding definitely doesn't really match the original question.